# PySide QScrollArea programatically scroll to specific child widget

Tags: python, pyside, qscrollarea

In PySide, I have set up a UI with a QScrollArea that has a QHBoxLayout, which contains custom QWidgets. After I populate the layout with my custom widgets, I want to programatically scroll to a specific widget so that it's in view, ideally at the top of the layout.

How how can a QScrollArea be set to scroll to the location of a specific widget in its layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QScrollArea.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QScrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible) works: `QScrollArea.ensureWidgetVisible(childWidget)`